# Showing data from DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, dataset, console-application

I am getting data in a dataset using entity framework from a stored procedure and now I have to show the data of specific columns in c# code. I tried WriteXML but its in xml format.
here is my code and I attached the photo of result of stored Procedure.[image]

```
DataSet myds = new DataSet();
            myds = new BLRestaurant().GetMenu();
            Console.WriteLine("Please select items from the menu listed:");
            Console.WriteLine("                                      Menu");
            Console.WriteLine(" -----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(" |  ID    |            ITEM             | ACTUAL PRICE  |  DISCOUNTED PRICE  | ");
            Console.WriteLine(" -----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
```

Comment: You didn't make it clear what your problem is.

Comment: You have provided a vague requirement but not a question? What are you asking?

Comment: I want to print data from dataset. but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(DataRow row in myds.Tables[0].Rows)
{    
    var id = row["ItemID"];
    var name = row["ItemName"];
}
```

Will get you the data for display. You can loop through the tables and get the column names as below if you are looking for something more generic:

```
IEnumerable<string> columns = tbl.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName);
```

Also you can merge the first 2 lines as instantiating a DataSet which immediately gets overwritten is poor memory management:

```
DataSet myds = new BLRestaurant().GetMenu();
```

Comment: is there any way that I can show data directly from dataset without using datatable?

Comment: @Umm-e-Habiba How would you know which table to use in the dataset without saying which one?

Comment: @Umm-e-Habiba You need to specify a table as you would specify a table when doing a select in sql

Comment: I am getting data from a stored procedure not from a table, thats why I want to print data directly from dataset.

Comment: @Umm-e-Habiba All the data is in the DataSet, which contains a collection of tables. You can then iterate through the rows in the table as shown.

Comment: My problem fixed with this foreach loop thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

As you're using .Net output it to a GridView

```
<asp:GridView Id="MyGridView" runat="server" />
```

then in the code behind do something like:

```
    private LoadGridView()
    {
        MyGridView.DataSource = GetMyData();
        MyGridView.DataBind();
    }

    private DataTable GetMyData()
    {
        DataTable result = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SQLConn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[MyStoreProcedure]", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            //Define parameters here
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //trap for errors
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Even if you don't want the GridView, you're better off putting the data into a DataTable as you can manipulate and iterate through it with statements like:

```
    foreach(DataRow dr in MyDataTable.Rows)
    {
        //do some stuff with the row
        //find a value in a column?
        string fieldText = dr["ColumnA"].Text;
    }
```